# wordpress - how to create a new blog template and blog page in existing wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, post, customization, blogs

I am very new in Wordpress.I have one wordpress site with a single template.I am trying to create a  new blog page in the same site.But when i created it looks like a page without style.How can i customize this new blog page. Please help or give some useful links.Thanks in advance.Please help me..

Comment: Have you read the WordPress documentation? http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
/*Template Name: Blog*/
?>
```

The very basic syntax to create a template in wordpress

Comment: I created a template like this <?php
/**
 * Template Name: Updated Blog Template

Comment: I created a template like you mentioned and assigned this template from backend.But this template is not showing in browser.Some default template is working behind.How can i check that.There is no duplicate template name.

Comment: It using index.php because i have no home.php.This was the issue.

Comment: Sorry for being late, you go to select the template while creating the page

The option is availble in the right side bar while creating a new page